# Stuck in Windows 10 Upgrade

Tags: windows, windows-10

My computer seems to be stuck in a Windows 10 failed upgrade loop. I was running fine on a beta version of Windows 10, and then I came downstairs one morning to see it repeatedly booting, attempting to repair, then rebooting. The steps I've taken to diagnose are:

- Attempting to boot off a USB drive (with all drives disabled in BIOS) - this fails at the point of the blue windows screen
- Attempting to boot the machine itself and getting into "repair/safe mode" using F7
- Looking at the BIOS for obvious failures (e.g. RAM that should be there is missing) - nothing obvious is wrong.

I am fairly certain the build version was 9926. For many months, the system would attempt to upgrade, and then say "it failed" for some reason and roll back.

Suggestions for next steps?

Comment: What build of the Insider Preview were you running before?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't remember :( I believe it was ~99xx something.

Comment: The thing that's concerning is that it won't even boot from the USB drive with all the internal drives disabled. That's surprising.

Comment: I am pretty sure 99xx builds expired awhile ago.  I hope this wasn't a product machine, its very likely, this isn't solvable.  You might want to try and determine what build it was exactly, provided that information, I can better explain what has happened.

Comment: But that doesn't totally explain why, even from a new USB (non-99xx build) it won't boot my machine.

Comment: I am fairly certain it was 9926.

Comment: [If it was build 9926, that is due to expire next month, but that isn't a guarantee that due future builds that didn't change at some point.](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/fyi-when-will-windows-10-build-9926-expire/29b2dfd6-6a71-46c1-83a6-888486c2e44b).  Sounds like you should pull the important stuff off the disk and properly install the RTM build of Windows 10.  This assumes you originally did a upgrade install.